# approximating probability distribution between two groups in R or Python

Tags: python, r

We recently ran an A/B test on the cancellation page of our subscription service. Before running the test, members were able to cancel using a simple web form. The experiment aims to measure the impact of forcing members to phone-in to our customer service line in order to cancel.

Two groups are defined, the `control group` that can cancel using a web form and the `test group` that can only cancel by calling in. Users were randomly assigned to a group when they go to the websites cancel page for the first-time. We have `sample_id` that is the unique identifier for the sample and `test_group` that is the group in which the sample was placed in which `0` is corresponding to `control group` and `1` is corresponding to the `test group`

How we can approximate the probability distribution between these two groups in R or python.

Comment: What do you mean to "approximate the probability distribution **between** these two groups"? Also, which event are you measuring? Time required to churn? If they churn or remain?

Comment: I want to approximate the distribution under which the sample assign to each group `control group` and test group`. Time does not require to churn.

Comment: You mean the probability that a person is assigned to either groups?

Comment: yes. The probability distribution

Comment: Doesn't it depend uniquely on how you have randomised the users?

Comment: If you currently only have access to the arity of the two sets, the best approximation *I believe* you can produce is an uniform with a threshold of separation.